# Transferring a Jquery object to a different input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on modifying a WordPress template for a client, one of the inputs I'm working with  has a class that shows a calendar. Whenever I call the the input on the console like so `jQuery("#booking_from_date")` it shows a jQuery object underneath it that says:

```
jQuery360045212629567534381: {events: {…}, hasDataAttrs: true, focus: false, handle: ƒ}
jQuery360045212629567534382: {singleDatePicker: false, autoApply: true, alwaysShowCalendars: true, autoUpdateInput: false, minDate: '05/22/2022', …}
```

the html of the input looks like this

```html
<input type="text" id="booking_from_date" size="40" name="booking_from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Check-In" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

it seems like these jQuery classes were added to the input via the id of the input
is there a way I can transfer those objects to a input with a different id? my goal is to be able to view the calendar when someone clicks on a different input with a different ID. I already tried using another input with the same id but the calendar will not show up. It seems like the calendar will only render the first input rendered on the page with ID of *"booking_from_date"*

Comment: It's not clear what is that you're trying to achieve. Could you be more specific and please, [edit] with a [mcve]? Read: [ask].

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. `jQuery("#booking_from_date")` is a selector, and typing that on the console shows you was matched. You can see it has some event handlders and it has been initialised as a `singleDatePicker`. If you want another datepicker on another intput, you need to initialise it in the same way this one was. Find the code that initialses it, and copy it for your other input. BTW HTML `id`s must be unique on the page.